# AsciiDoc navigation panel

Tags: menu, navigation, ascii, doc, asciidoc

How i can create a left navigation panel in AsciiDoc?

like this one here https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/

[image]

not a list of contents.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The example you provide is a list of contents. Do you want a sidebar on the left with nothing in it?

Comment: I know that it looks like a list of contents but it isnt, I have attached another printscreen showing on the right what is really the list of content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navigation pane in your screenshot includes links to many HTML files. `asciidoctor` doesn't have any built-in facility for generating multiple HTML files from an Asciidoc markup file.

To do that for your own Asciidoc content, you need a tool that processes many Asciidoc files and generates an entire site. Such tools are called static site generators. There are many, and quite a few support Asciidoc markup, including Hugo, Jekyll, and Eleventy.

The Asciidoctor documentation was generated with a tool called [Antora](https://antora.org/), which was created by the author of `asciidoctor`. Its goal is to specifically support generating technical documentation web sites (and eventually PDF documents) from Asciidoc markup.

Many companies with large sets of technical documentation use Antora. [This page](https://gitlab.com/antora/antora.org/-/issues/20) lists the companies and sites using Antora, plus public repos with the implementations (where available).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in my opinion ist to use ASCIIDOC option ":toc:".
For your use case you should set :toc:left in the header of your asciidoc File.

Comment: It seems like this generates a Table of Contents for the sections within a page, but not an overview of the different pages. So the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478123/asciidoc-navigation-panel/74495935#74495935) is more accurate.